# Update part of record firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire

i have firebase node called
  `comment{textCmnt, dateCmnt}`
I try this code to update only the textCmnt but i get all the node updated.

```
var obj = $firebaseObject(ref.child('/comment/'+$scope.c.$id));
obj.textCmnt="new text"; 
obj.$save();
```

Any help please.

Answer (score 0):

There is no method built into AngularFire for that. Luckily AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, which has a method just for that purpose:

```
ref.update({ textCmnt: "new text" });
```

And since AngularFire is built on top of that, they interoperate perfectly.